# Reference inline SVG in CSS pseudo element?

Tags: css, svg

This is a long shot... I'd like to have an svg shape appear before every h3 element, but which changes color with the class of the div it appears in. I understand that I can't do it by referencing a separate svg file through the "content" property.

Is there a way I can do it by referencing an inline svg - through the content property or otherwise?! As the actual text on the site will be written by users who can't use html, I can't simply hard-code it before every h3 element...

Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't think so, you could just create a custom icon font and use that instead. The content property (in a pseudo-element) would automatically inherit the text color of the `h3`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible.  You need access to the svg's `stroke` or `fill` property to change the colour.  Images added to the pseudo-element's `content` property (e.g. `content: url(my.svg)` is [generated content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html) and as such should just be seen as a flat image. Only the 'box' that is the pseudo-element is able to be modified through css.

Ideally, you would inject the svg inline into the DOM.  However, you would still need to edit both the `color` property for the `h3` text and either the `stroke` or `fill` property for the svg as well.  As mentioned by Paulie_D in his comment, an icon font would get around this and inherit the `color` from the `h3` tag.  You can even create a custom icon font with your svg(s) with something like [this](http://fontcustom.com/).